# Windows UAC wont allow access to ubuntu folder?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba

I have a web server set up on a secondary machine running Ubuntu. I want to be able to access the folder in which I keep the text documents for the server from multiple machines. So I can have I went in and set this particular folder to shared with the check box for allow others to create and delete folders checked. Now I go to my windows machine and click the computer on the network it opens and I see the shared folder. I click to access the folder and the Windows UAC opens. I then type \10.10.11.120\Agent47 (this is the IP address of the Ubuntu computer followed by the username (I type the IP address because I'm on a domain that the server is not on)) then I type in my password (the password of the owner of the folder which is Agent47) and it does nothing just reopens the UAC. Has anyone ever encountered a problem like this before or know what I'm doing wrong (I'm relatively new to Ubuntu and linux in general btw)? 
THX,
Logan

Comment: My thought is that the file that is trying to be accessed, needs root permission, and Windows only has simple permissions. I'd give you an answer using `sudo chown` but I do not know what you would change user permissions to to allow an outside operating system to access them

Comment: I had changed the permissions to the owner account on the ubuntu machine. I was hoping that would allow my to use that username and password to access the folder. It did not. I'm now thinking that since windows doesn't care about capitalization on usernames that it is removing the capitol "A" and making it a lower case "a" and this is causing the error. I'm not sure though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so all you have to do is:

`sudo chown 777 [filename]`

Obviously replacing `[filename]` with the name of the text documents

Comment: What does this do other than change the owner?
and what would the username and password be on the windows machine?